# How to rebuild android adb tool for mac

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-sdk-manager

I have modification for android **ADB** tool source code, but i need to rebuild for Mac.

Could someone share your suggestion please!!

Thanks

Comment: the sources you have contain `Android.mk`, dont they?

Comment: Yes, i have AOSP code with linux environment setup.

Also  i tried with [link](https://github.com/karfield/adb) link with mac machine. but facing error with **Error: No available formula with the name "Adb4Mac" **

Comment: try https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/tree/master/adb

Comment: Thank you, Could you please guide me to build standalone for specific project(/system/core/)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/build.html